# Changing node module installation 'where' path in package.json

Tags: node.js

I am new in nodejs and trying to deploy the dev environment to production environment. I copied the files from dev to production and now when I open package.json from one node module then I can see in `where` the path is referring to the dev installation path.

```
"_where": "/var/www/api-dev",
```

What will be the quickest way to change the values to point to production path for all modules.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think `_where` plays a role here. From npm discussion boards on the subject, the consensus seems to remove that line manually. The node modules should be installed to the `node_modules` directory based on the `dependencies` and `dev-dependencies` in the `package.json` file when you do `npm install`. Just make sure you have all the dependencies stated.

Comment: on another note: what I'm doing to put my code into production, is to enclose my nodejs apps in a docker image. I can include an example `Dockerfile` in an answer if you find this reasonable for your case